# fiddler 2 with framesets

Tags: internet-explorer, fiddler

I needed a tool for debugging ajax requests and responses. Somebody recommended using fiddler 2. Now my problem is I am working on an application that has framesets. One on the left for nav, one on the top for some more nav where the main application is underneath. When I click on things, all I see on fiddler 2 is :

```
 200 http tunnel to blah.com and then the port number.
```

In the webforms, or webview section, I don't see any of these ajax variables. Is there a way to make this thing work when there are framesets?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Framesets. If you look at the 200 HTTP Tunnel using the inspectors, it will point out that you need to enable HTTPS Decryption if you want to see HTTPS traffic in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

**Could you provide an example of the code you are using?**

I'm using Fiddler at the moment to debug a ASP.NET app and have used it while developing in HTML, PHP and jQuery.

#### A word on frames

First, if at all possible I would not use frames in your implementation. They are depreciated in HTML5 and will be going the way of the dodo soon enough! ([Frames Suck Most of the Time](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9612.html)). Instead, you could look at using iFrames, Ajax requests or even [CSS](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200609/css_frames_v2_fullheight/) (which mimics a frames 'look').

Now onto the problem. I'm assuming that your using both frames AND JavaScript Ajax code.

**Check Fiddler**

Fiddler logs Ajax requests like any other. It doesn't discriminate and usually catches absolutely everything. First, double check fiddler by navigating to goggles’ live search. If you can see the multiple Ajax requests as you type a search string, then its your implementation (frames/Ajax) that’s the problem and not Fiddler.

**If its your implementation**

Without more information on your code / implimentation try the following to troubleshoot:

1. Try the Ajax code you are using on a page without frames. Does that work?
2. Try a normal link within your frame, when clicked does that show up in Fiddler?

**If its Fiddler, use Firebug**

If Fiddler isn't working out, try Firebug. Its a great Firefox ad-on and the "nets" tab will give you all requests/responses.